# Typescript with strict mode shows error "Object is possibly 'undefined'" but it is not

Tags: typescript

Consider the following short example:

```js
type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string | undefined;
}

export function testUser(user: User) {
  const userIsValid = !!user && !!user.name;
  if(userIsValid) console.log(user.name.length);
}
```

And strict mode actived in tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

When I run `tsc` I got an error:

```
index.ts:8:31 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

8   if(userIsValid) console.log(user.name.length);
                                ~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in index.ts:8

error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

But everyone know that is impossible to be undefined inside that if clause.

Is it a bug?

Comment: No, it's _not_ a bug. `userIsValid` is just a boolean, it doesn't narrow the type of `user` at all. Maybe you want a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, TypeScript can't narrow the type of one variable/property based on another variable/property,¹ even when to us humans it's (fairly) obvious that (in this case) `userIsValid` is only true when `user` and `user.name` are both truthy. It just doesn't do analysis to that level. **However**, in *some* situations, TypeScript 4.4 and above **can** do that analysis — see [jcalz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72464198/157247) for how you could do that with `Readonly`.

But before v4.4 or if you can't use a readonly object, use the variable itself:

```typescript
type User = {
    id: number;
    name: string | undefined;
};

export function testUser(user: User) {
    if (user.name) {
        console.log(user.name.length);
    }   
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBT1ASwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIyQG4d8KBDaiMuYRA8gcygAfKJXJEIAMz4QiTbAF95OCAA8wAe0TAoksQGNgBDeSjAI3eEgAUlBIjJXEASgzN8BSVFv2AdOXYIVyxcFnx9EzgNABsIX2iNfh8kf0D4iAFgAAtneRYFfBwFIA)

*(Note there's no need to test `user`. As [Mike S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13258211/mike-s) said in a comment, it's not optional or nullable, so you can trust that it refers to a `User` object.)*

---

¹ It can narrow the type of an object based on an object property, and narrow types in various ways, but not the kind of thing you're doing in your question.

Comment: OK I see.

To preserve a clean code, I like to create variables that represents a complex boolean logic, and typescript is not good for that.

Comment: @JeffersonFelix You can go the extra length and create a type predicate [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyRywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcBxVctEl6YUoA5sgA+yaiFIQYoCKRb4AvgQKhIsRCgByHGRix5CxMpRoNmrYiG3deAuYvwEYYhGGAB7ECXRbOpXVAAKOAB9akwoSn8ASkoQsKxgdGQfHXCccyIoCDBqKE848IA6S05kAEIAXgrRcUlpWQJ7AggADwAHNygwZCcQF3dPSB5-APiItHCo9INgGADElL9w0cmphA90NwAbCEKtt34V6GLtPYgQfjAACyi7IA). This does create a little overhead, but should be more compliant with "clean code"

Comment: @JeffersonFelix - Frankly, I wouldn't consider that clean. A type predicate function for complex logic is definitely clean, but a boolean variable defined in one place and used to protect against unexpected `undefined` in another place doesn't to me. Obviously, opinions will differ. :-)

Comment: TypeScript is actually "good" for such aliased conditions, as of TypeScript 4.4.  It just needs to be confident that such conditions can't be invalidated (e.g., the possibility that `user.name` will be reassigned somewhere).  See my answer to this question for more information.

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks for that!! Very interesting. I value your opinion: Would you call the answer above *wrong* or merely incomplete? (In the former case, I'll delete it. In the latter, I've added a note and a link to yours to add completeness.) Thanks again for that!

Comment: I think your answer was right before TS4.4 (and if I had written an answer then I’d’ve pointed to the relevant feature request) and now is just incomplete (except you’ve added the missing info now)

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript 4.4 introduced support for [control flow analysis of aliased conditions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants) like your `userIsValid` boolean value.  However, because tracking such dependencies in general could be very taxing on the compiler, it only works in certain situations.  The `name` property of `User` is not [a `readonly` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties), so it is possible someone could write `user.name = undefined` after your `userIsValid` test.  This possibility means the compiler gives up on narrowing in your code, since otherwise it would need to check that such an assignment does not occur, which is expensive in the general case.

An easy enough fix for that is to make `user` a read-only version of `User`, e.g., a `Readonly<User>` using [the `Readonly<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype):

```
export function testUser(user: Readonly<User>) {
  const userIsValid = !!user && !!user.name;
  if (userIsValid) console.log(user.name.length); // okay
}
```

That works because the compiler is now at least somewhat confident that your code won't reassign `user.name` anywhere, and so `userIsValid` is the sort of aliased condition it will track.

Note that, in general, a `User` and a `Readonly<User>` are mutually assignable; a `readonly` property is a declaration of developer intent that it will not be reassigned in the relevant scope; it's not a guarantee of immutability.  So the compiler doesn't prevent you from passing a `User` into a function that wants a `Readonly<User>`:

```
const u: User = {id: 123, name: "alice"};
testUser(u); // okay
```

which is good, since it means the change to `testUser()` I made has no annoying effects on callers.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgSwBMAuKAOwFcBbAIyQG4c8yBDKiUuYRfMgcygAfKBTKEIAM14RCjbAF8cOCAA8wAe0TAoE0QGNg+dWSjAIXeEgAUFBIlIAlCC0LGANiAA8lxAD4AlBhMUHrGXCJ2AJJwAGosbkSoUACEybZIUABkmSlpdgB0rOxyePgSUDZRsfFEgaFkcOpuEPlu6nyVSIVsLc38wAAW-nKK2Dj14RSkPknoRKQAjABMAMwANOQ9pABENXoQ2-JyZhZ2NsNQAPSXUOoA1iwgQA)